# Xcode build succeeded but close unwaited

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, testflight

Al realizar el proceso de 'Archive' se da compilación correctamente pero el entorno se cierra inesperadamente y por tanto no se genera el archive lo cual impide continuar con el proceso en testFlight.

Comment: Please write your question in English https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Answer (score 0):

Select Window -> Organizer, and you will see your archives